# Python ctypes variable content issue

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using the following DLL function

```
int ReadMemU32(long address , long *pdata)
```

i'm using it with *ctypes byref* like this:

```
read_data =  c_ulong(0)
result = ReadMemU32(address, byref(read_data))
```

when i checked its value i notice this:

```
>>> read_data
c_ulong(55L)
>>> read_data == 55
False
>>> read_data == c_ulong(55L)
False
```

why its false?

if instead i do:

```
# my_memory is of type Class(Structure) with c_ulong field names read_data
my_memory.read_data = read_data
```

and check the result:

```
>>> my_memory.read_data 
55L
>>> my_memory.read_data == 55
True
```

what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your code, just use:

```
read_data.value == 55
```

The motive why :

```
>>> read_data == c_ulong(55L)
False
```

happens is because ctyps does not implement proper Python comparison for C objects - it tests for object identity, as is the default. If you compare the ".value" property of each object, though, you are fine.

Comment: So why assignment to structure with c_ulong field behaves differently?

Comment: Because acessing properties on Ctypes struct classes coerce the values in the fields back to Python numeric objects - you can see that by simply printing repr(my_memory.read_data) as co9mpared to repr(read_data) in your example above.